# Huge performance difference with Iperf between - with and without VPN Tunnel

Tags: performance, docker, networking, vpn, iperf

I am running some performance measures between the different network settings using **IPerf**. I see very drastic differences between two basic setups.

1. Two containers *(docker)* connected to each other via the default **docker0** bridge interface in the host.
2. Two containers connected via a **VPNTunnel interface** that is internally connected via the above *docker0* bridge.

***IPerf*** calculation for both scenarios for ***10sec***

```
**Scenario One (1)**  

Client connecting to 172.17.0.4, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 1.12 MByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 172.17.0.2 port 50728 connected with 172.17.0.4 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  3.26 GBytes  28.0 Gbits/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  3.67 GBytes  31.5 Gbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  3.70 GBytes  31.8 Gbits/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  3.93 GBytes  33.7 Gbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  3.34 GBytes  28.7 Gbits/sec
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  3.44 GBytes  29.6 Gbits/sec
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  3.55 GBytes  30.5 Gbits/sec
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  3.50 GBytes  30.0 Gbits/sec  
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  3.41 GBytes  29.3 Gbits/sec
[  3]  9.0-10.0 sec  3.20 GBytes  27.5 Gbits/sec
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  35.0 GBytes  30.1 Gbits/sec


**Scenario Two (2)**

Client connecting to 10.23.0.2, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 10.12.0.2 port 41886 connected with 10.23.0.2 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  15.1 MBytes   127 Mbits/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  14.9 MBytes   125 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  14.9 MBytes   125 Mbits/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  14.2 MBytes   120 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  16.4 MBytes   137 Mbits/sec
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  18.0 MBytes   151 Mbits/sec
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  18.6 MBytes   156 Mbits/sec
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  16.4 MBytes   137 Mbits/sec
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  13.5 MBytes   113 Mbits/sec
[  3]  9.0-10.0 sec  15.0 MBytes   126 Mbits/sec
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   157 MBytes   132 Mbits/sec
```

I am confused as to the high differences in throughput.

Is it due to the encryption and decryption and OpenSSL involved that makes this degradation?

Or is it because of the need for unmarshalling and marshalling of packet headers below the application layer more than once when routing through the VPN tunnel?

Thank You
Shabir

Answer (score 0):

Both tests did not run equally - the first test ran with a TCP window of 1.12 Mbyte, while the second slower test ran with a window of 0.085 MByte:

```
Client connecting to 172.17.0.4, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 1.12 MByte (default)
                 ^^^^

Client connecting to 10.23.0.2, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
                 ^^^^
```

Thus, it's possible that you're experiencing TCP window exhaustion, both because of the smaller buffer and because of the mildly increased latency through the vpn stack.

In order to know what buffer size to use (if not just a huge buffer), you need to know your [bandwidth-delay product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product).

I don't know what your original channel RTT is, but we can take a stab at it. You were able to get ~30 gbit/sec over your link with a buffer size of 1.12 MBytes, then doing the math backwards (unit conversions elided), we get:

`1.12 megabytes / 30 gigabits/sec --> 0.3 ms`.

That seems reasonable. Now let's assume your vpn has double the RTT than the original link, so we'll assume a latency of 0.6 ms. Then, we'll use your new window size of 0.085 MByte to figure out what kind of performance you should expect by calculating the bandwidth-delay product forwards:

```
0.085 Mbytes / 0.6 ms --> BDP = 141 mbit/sec.
```

Well, what do you know, that's about the exact performance you're seeing.

If, for example, you wanted to saturate a 100 gigabit/sec pipe with a RTT of 0.6 ms, then you would need a buffer size of 7.5 Mbytes. Alternatively if you wanted to saturate the pipe not with a single connection but with N connections, then you'd need N sockets each with a send buffer size of 7.5/N Mbytes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I think that TCP window above was random and only denotes the window at the beginning of **iperf**. I tried it running again and the window was set to **85 KByte** by default for both scenarios. I tried manually setting the Window to 400KB and still am seeing difference of huge magnitude.

Comment: Try setting the window/buffer size to something like 10 Mbytes to be absolutely sure. 400 Kbytes is still far too small. Also, check cpu usage during the scenario. Is the VPN software saturating a core, or using all cpu?